# objective-c iphone programming : remote connection database iphone

Tags: iphone, database

i simply want to make an iphone application with a remote database. For exemple facebook iphone application, they have all access to a huge database. Are they using Mysql ? Because i heard that mysql is not secure through iphone and app store may reject it. Can someone help me figure out whats the best to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What all those apps are probably using is a RESTful web service endpoint that is in turn backed by a large database. There are a lot of libraries for creating web services regarding of what application stack you're using.

If you're using MySQL, you'd write a Python/Ruby/Whatever-you-choose backend component which actually connects to a MySQL instance, then reformat the results as a web-service endpoint. SOAP can work if need be, or (in my opinion) a better option would be to write a simple JSON service that your iPhone app can parse. There are lots of JSON/WS iOS libraries that are a google query away.

Comment: JSON parsing is great.! and it is multi-platform as any device like Android or any tablets can still use it.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will not be bothered what database you are use remotely (will be accessed through defined API's).